# Dojo Textarea trigger onChange after manual change

Tags: events, dojo, textarea

An existing Dojo 1.10 page has the following HTML textarea (I don't have the ability to change the source code):

```
<textarea tabindex="40" data-qbo-bind="value: payeeMessage" class="customerMessage" data-dojo-attach-point="_gridTabTarget" maxlength="1000"></textarea>
```

I have been trying to create a javascript that will change the content of the textarea so that the value is saved with the form is submitted. I have been able to change the content but it never gets saved because somehow, I need to produce an onChange trigger event after changing the value.

My code looks like this but, it does not trigger the event:

```
dojo.query(".customerMessage").connect("onchange", function() { alert("Changed!"); });
var widget_node = dojo.query(".customerMessage")[0];
widget_node.innerHTML="123123";
widget_node.onchange();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: have tried with `onkeyup` and `onblur` events instead of `onchange`

Comment: Welcome on SO! Please post a jsfiddle so we can better answer. Thanks!

Comment: I tried the onkeyup but the behavior is the same. As on the jsFIddle I just posted, the event only gets triggered if I modify the textarea manually

Answer (score 0):

Get your widget and use `this.set('value', value)` to update your widget with the value passed by `change` event.

Example (Please open console):

https://jsfiddle.net/s5620bwd/3/

```
require(['dijit/form/TextBox', 'dojo/on'], function(TextBox, on) {
  var textBox = new TextBox({
    intermediateChanges: true
  }, 'button');
  on(textBox, 'change', function(value) {
    this.set('value', value);
    console.log(this.get('value')); // widget updated
  });
});
```

---

```
<div id="button"></div>
```

---

In your code, you should add `this.set('value', value);` within callBack  for  `onChange`.

Comment: Thank you but I could not find how to apply your code to the jsFiddle example I just posted. I see in yours, you are creating a new textarea but I need to retrieve an existing one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having problems with the `change` event not working as intended for `textarea` elements, you may want to add `data-dojo-props="intermediateChanges: true"` to the `textarea`.